# SEPIC converter capacitors calculation

Tags: dc-dc-converter, sepic

I have got a SEPIC converter design see here:
http://www.linear.com/docs/27994
The calculation of the SEPIC converter starts at page 21.
For the input capacitance on page 17 they tell you need:

\$I_{RMS}(C_{IN}) = 0.3 \cdot ∆I_L \$

This is a current and not a capacitance how can I calculate a capacitance value from this current?

On page 24 they calculate the coupling capacitor current:

\$I_{RMS}(C_{DC})\$

but again this is no capacitance. How can I calculate a capacitance from this current?

Comment: Can you paste the schematic as an image in the question?  That way if the link breaks the question will still be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheet (on page 17, right above your \$I_{RMS} = 0.3 \Delta I_L\$ equation):

> The  input  capacitor  of  a  boost  converter  is  less  critical than the output capacitor, due to the fact that the inductor is  in  series  with  the  input,  and  the  input  current  waveform is continuous. **The input voltage source impedance determines the size of the input capacitor, which is typically in the range of 10μF to 100μF**. A low ESR capacitor is recommended, although it is not as critical as for the output capacitor.

This is basically saying: it depends.  If your upstream source is close by and decently stiff, a smaller input capacitance (~10μF) will suffice.  If the supply is further away or has a high output impedance, a larger capacitor (~100μF) is needed.

Similar to a [boost converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter), the input current is constant so the capacitors won't need to quickly supply a large amount of current.  This is opposed to a [buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) whose input current is discontinuous and thus a higher amount of input capacitance is desired, especially for high-output-impedance upstream supplies.

In my experience, designing input capacitance can be kind of an iterative process.  Put a reasonable amount (i.e. guess) in, observe the input voltage ripple (right at the input to the converter), and adjust as needed.